# Is there a term for this graph subset?

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-colorings, definitions

Suppose $G$ is a (finite) graph which is $k$-vertex colourable (i.e. $\chi(G)\leqslant k$). Suppose $S$ is a set of vertices of $G$ with the following property:

If $c:V(G)\rightarrow [k]$ is a vertex colouring of $G$ with $k$ colours, then the restriction of $c$ to $S$ is surjective. In other words, $c(S)=[k]$. That is, whenever the vertices of $G$ are coloured with $k$ colours, every colour appears at least once on $S$.

I would like to know the technical term (if there is one) for this property of $S$. I have been unable to find information on this concept online. When I first considered such sets, I called $S$ a "$k$-rainbow set" for $G$. However, I quickly realised that this term is already used in reference to "rainbow paths", which is a very different concept.

References to any research that has been done on these sets would also be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: A common observation made in the comments is that the existence of a "$k$-rainbow set" of $G$ is equivalent to $k=\chi (G)$. It then seems odd that the name is given in terms of $k$ rather than $\chi$. The reason I phrased it as such is because, when I originally came upon this idea, I was considering subgraphs of $G$ and looking at their "rainbow sets". Hence it was necessary to keep track of a varying $k$ which might be less than $\chi(G)$.

Comment: Hmm I do not know of any standard terminology for such a set, but it seems to be a natural concept. The property that you are describing is equivalent to saying that there does not exist a $(k-1)$-colouring of $S$ which extends to a proper colouring of $G$. So, perhaps a name like "non-$(k-1)$-extendible" would be appropriate.

Comment: I like "$k$-rainbow" better than "non-($k-1$)-extendible" :) Perhaps a variation on this theme such as "$k$-prismatic" or "$k$-polychromatic" might be a good name?

Comment: Perhaps something like "$k$-chromatic core" is a possibility, although "core" is unfortunately also already used in graph theory.

Comment: Since $S$ may not have chromatic number $k$ by itself, it would be good to use terminology that doesn't suggest that it does.

Comment: How about 'witness for chromatic number'?  Gerhard "Gives It A CS Flavor" Paseman, 2017.06.16.

Comment: I think this is only interesting if $k= \chi(G)$ otherwise only the whole vertex set has this property. I'd use something like $\chi$-witness set or $\chi$-intersecting set (it intersects every color class) or always $\chi$-colored set (maybe ACC set as an abbreviation).

Comment: Thank you for all of your comments so far. I have made an edit to address the matter of $k$ being equal to $\chi(G)$. I hope this explains why I originally phrased "rainbow sets" in terms of $k$ rather than $\chi$.

Comment: Such a set is a 'transversal' of every partition of the vertex-set into independent sets, so I'd maybe call it a 'chromatic transversal'. You might also say that it intersects every independent set $X$ for which $G - X$ is $(k-1)$-colourable.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins What is an example of a subset $S$ that has the property described in the question, but $\chi(S)<k$ when $S$ is considered as an induced subgraph? Can $\chi(S)$ become arbitrarily small with respect to $k$?

Comment: @DominicvanderZypen It seems to me that you can make examples where $S$ is discrete---no edges at all and hence 1-colorable---but still must have $k$ colors when the whole of $G$ is $k$-colored, because of how $S$ relates to the other nodes of $G$, which are not in $S$. To give a simple example, consider a 6-cycle, which has chromatic number 2, and let $S$ be the nodes 1 and 4. So $S$ is discrete, but any coloring of the 6-cycle will place two different colors on the nodes of $S$. I'm sure you can make more extreme examples.

Comment: @DominicvanderZypen Furthermore, it can be shown that for any positive integer $k$ and any graph $H$ of order $k$, there exists a graph $G$ with a $k$-rainbow set $S$ (so $\chi(G)=k$) such that the subgraph of $G$ induced by $S$ is [isomorphic to] $H$.

Comment: @DominicvanderZypen Take a graph $H$ on n vertices that is $k$-colorable. Add $\binom{n}{k-1}$ extra vertices and join these to the $(k-1)$ sets of $H$. Then the resulting graph is still $k$-colorable, and the additional set of vertices is independent (or stable) satisfies the required property.